# JSONAPI Resources, need a filter for the last record

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, json-api, jsonapi-resources

so I'm looking at creating a filter for a JSONAPI resource where I'll grab anything created within the last 10 minutes and return only one result if something's there.

Problem, when I call .last(1) on the returned records I get an error:

```
"exception": "undefined method `order' for #<Array:0x007fde4770bcf0>"
```

My non-breaking query is this:

```
records.where(user_id: user_id, updated_at: ten_minutes_ago..current_time)
```

Any help? I'd like to do this on the Rails-side rather than deal with a mangle of results (or no results) on our front-end. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so the deal is this.

In order to grab only 1 record you'll probably have to overwrite/define your own paginator, like so:

```
paginator :none
```

I'd put it after your attributes and before your filters. Cool? Cool. Next, you can just do your basic Rails querying:

```
records.where(user_id: user_id, updated_at: ten_minutes_ago..current_time)
.order(id: :desc)
.limit(1)
```

You need to set your paginator or else the defaults or whatever you've defined will overwrite your limit query. Sweet. Easy.